# Assigning a float to a decimal property via a style setter in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, casting, styles, setter

I have the following xaml in a template for a lookless control:

```
<Style x:Key="NumericUpDownStyle" TargetType="controls:NumericUpDown">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Change" Value="{x:Static local:Preferences.ChangeAmount}"/>
    </Style.Setters>
</Style>
```

Where the `Change` property on the `NumericUpDown` control is a decimal, and the static `Preferences.ChangeAmount` is a float.

This fails with the following error:

**'1' is not a valid value for property 'Change'**

Is there a way to get the style to cast the float to a decimal?  It is not an option to change the `NumericUpDown` control, the underlying control that I am templating, or the `Preferences.ChangeAmount` property.  I can make some static wrapper properties somewhere to do the casting but that seems silly to me.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `{x:Static ...}` Markup Extension directly, you could try to wrap it in a `Binding` like that:

```
<Setter Property="Change" Value="{Binding Source={x:Static local:Preferences.ChangeAmount}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

This might already work as the `Binding` typically takes care of necessary conversions. If it does not work, you could add an appropriate `IValueConverter` to the `Binding`.

To improve performance you could also set the `Mode` property to `OneTime` instead of `OneWay`. However, I am not sure whether this will work. Good luck!